# Unity Android Screen Capture Plugin

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, screen, capture

I'm in the process of developing a custom Unity Plugin (Android) that allows the Unity application to record the screen.  I've looked at several existing Unity plugins and none seem to either work or do exactly what I'm needing.  I was able to get a VERY simple Android plugin (.jar) built and loaded into Unity using this nice [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ahGeTNUPLM).

To be clear... this is my very first attempt at creating a Unity plugin.

My problem is that when I extend the Activity my plugin fails to function.  When debugging, the log cat doesn't enter the onCreate() method and the Log.d() message isn't thrown. Any help on identifying if the below source code is valid would be great.  This code is nothing like the tutorial I watched.  Much more involved.

BTW, I first built the below code in Android Studio and ran on a device to make sure the code actually performed as expected.  It did. I then took the code from that initial test and started developing the Unity plugin below based on the video tutorial and other resources.

Here's my Android Java code that builds the classes.jar file with no build errors.

```
 package lib.rrpartners.com.unityscreencaptureplugin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ScreenCapturePlugin extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "ScreenCapturePlugin";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private int mScreenDensity;
    private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;
    private static final int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 1440;
    private static final int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 2560;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback;
    private ToggleButton mToggleButton;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 10;

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return "Some text here";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("OverrideActivity", "onCreate called!");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mScreenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService
                (Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unknown request code: " + requestCode);
            return;
        }
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mToggleButton.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }
        mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
        mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
        mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }

    public void startScreenRecording() {
        initRecorder();
        startScreenRecording();

        if (mMediaProjection == null) {
            startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }

    private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {
        return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity",
                DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, mScreenDensity,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null
                /*Handler*/);
    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                            .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/video.mp4");
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            if (mToggleButton.isChecked()) {
                mToggleButton.setChecked(false);
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.reset();
                Log.v(TAG, "Recording Stopped");
            }
            mMediaProjection = null;
            stopScreenSharing();
        }
    }

    private void stopScreenSharing() {

        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();

        if (mVirtualDisplay == null) {
            return;
        }
        mVirtualDisplay.release();
        //mMediaRecorder.release(); //If used: mMediaRecorder object cannot
        // be reused again
        destroyMediaProjection();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        destroyMediaProjection();
    }

    private void destroyMediaProjection() {
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            mMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback);
            mMediaProjection.stop();
            mMediaProjection = null;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "MediaProjection Stopped");
    }

}
```

Here's my Android Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="lib.rrpartners.com.unityscreencaptureplugin">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Unity C# Code

```
frameCount = GameObject.Find("FrameCount").GetComponent<Text>();

        using (AndroidJavaClass cls_UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        {
            using (AndroidJavaObject obj_Activity = cls_UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
            {
                obj_Activity.CallStatic("onCreate");
            }
        }
```

Comment: A quick search brings up this documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidAARPlugins.html so you may want to clarify what approach you are taking

Comment: Yeah, I've crossed that same reference and many other examples very similar.  Each reference slightly similar in their approach.  Also, I'm not extending the UnityPlayerActivity.  Or should I be?  I'm asking for clarification on the source code approach.

Comment: I haven't tried to create a Unity plug-in to do game play capture but if I were I would go with a UnityPlayerActivity and a simple scene. In your existing C# code you are calling a Android framework method `onCreate` directly (a no-no).  Related I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211613/screen-recorder-android-plugin-in-unity Since gameplay capture involves performance hits, hardware limitations and a understanding of the Android framework - I wish you luck.